# Convert date like "Wednesday, 21 May, 2014" to timestamp

Tags: php

I formated a datepicker with this format : dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy'.

Then I have a form,

If user dont choose a date then it will assume the current date in this format: echo date('l, j F, Y - H:i:s'); and save in database.

If user fill the input date, so I want to save in database this filled date.

The problem is, in my database Im getting date like this: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Im trying to use strototime to convert date to timestamp but Im not having sucess doing this.

Do you know How we can do this?

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker"  name="date" value="if(isset($_POST['date'])) echo strtotime($f['date']); else echo date('l, j F, Y - H:i:s'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to insert into the database. From the sounds of it, you're possibly trying to save a timestamp into a datetime field in mysql?

Comment: Note that if $_POST['date'] isset that you echo a timestamp. In the other case you echo a human readable format. 
What contains $f[date']?

Answer (score 1):

> *Convert date like `'Wednesday, 21 May, 2014'` to `timestamp`*

I am not sure, how you are using the input with `insert` statement.
But you should have used proper date_format string so that `MySQL` interprets it as valid `datetime` string.

**Example**:

```
select @dt:='Wednesday, 21 May, 2014' dt, 
       str_to_date( @dt, '%W, %d %M, %Y' ) ts;
```

What I think that you have used a wrong format string. You better use `'%W, %d %M, %Y'`.

**Example**:

```
insert 
  into   table_name( timstamp_field )
 values( str_to_date( $date_time_input_by_user, '%W, %d %M, %Y' ) )
```

And unless this is from user input, you have to use different `MySQL` format string that matches with `PHP` date format string `''l, j F, Y - H:i:s''`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
    $date = strtotime("Wednesday, 21 May 2014 18:32:09");
    $newformat = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
?>
```